# Find count of number of matched values in MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB, I want to find the document that have few or all values in them as specified in condition and find count of how many values matched.

My sudo target document:

```
{  "name":"room1",
   "colors":["red","blue","green"],
   "objects":["chair","bed"]
}
```

Now i want the documents that have any of the colors and any of the objects present in "room1". It should give result if even 1 or all of the color,objects are found.

```
{  "name":"room2",
   "colors":["blue","green"],
   "objects":["chair","bed","sofa","fridge"]
}

{  "name":"room3",
   "colors":["yellow","pink"],
   "objects":["chair"]
}
```

So the result should be as:
for room2: matchcount=4 as it shares 4 common values with room1
for room3: matchcount=1 as it shares 1 common value with room1

So far I have tried using $in and aggregate function to find count, it finds the documents with similar values in them but counting what is the match count is still a issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose your collection name is "room", then query will be this :

```
db.room.aggregate([{
    $match: { colors: { $in: ["red","blue","green"] } }
  }, {$project:{matchedColorCount:{
   $size: { 
         "$setIntersection": [["red","blue","green"], '$colors' ] 
       }
  }}}])
```

Here, `$match: { colors: { $in: ["red","blue","green"] }` will tell which colors need to be find in the document.
and `"$setIntersection": [["red","blue","green"], '$colors' ]` will extract the matched colors from the particular document.
`$size` will provide the matched count of colors.